# zgrep in hadoop streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

I am trying to grep a zip file on S3/aws & write the output to a new location with same file name

I am using below on s3 , is this the right way to write the streaming output from first CAT command to hdfs output?

```
hadoop fs -cat s3://analytics/LZ/2017/03/03/test_20170303-000000.tar.gz | zgrep -a -E '*word_1*|*word_2*|word_3|word_4' | hadoop fs -put - s3://prod/project/test/test_20170303-000000.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Given you are playing with hadoop, why not run the code in cluster? Scanning for strings inside a .gzip file is commonplace, though I don't know about .tar files.
2. I'd personally use the `-copyToLocal` and `-copyFromLocal` commands to copy it to the local FS and work there. The trouble with things like `-cat` is that a lot gets logged out on the Hadoop client code, so a pipe is likely to pick up too much extraneous cruft,